# ng-include melhora a performance do site?

Tags: html, angularjs, desempenho

**Boa tarde**

Gostaria de saber se eu separar o html em partes e usar o ng-include para adicioná-los ao index, melhora a performance do site? deixando-o mais veloz

Grato desde já !!

Comment: Creio eu que é muito relativo, quase impossível de afirmar, depende muito da aplicação, do que ela vai conter, se existir um problema de performance muito grande, provavelmente é por outro motivo, remendos não irão concertar se a origem disto for em outro lugar.

Comment: Ajuda na manutenibilidade mas perde em desempenho, afinal ng-include irá requisitar o HTML, nada tão grave mas é uma requisição a mais, tem outras opções como SPA, requisita só o que foi pedido, mas perde em build inicial.